# Sitecore How Access Rights Affect Each Other

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore6

for example, 2 extranet roles in sitecore Role1 and Role2
Role1 is block access to item, Role2 - allow access.

I need to have behavior that revers default sitecore behavior:

> 5.3 How Access Rights Affect Each Other In Sitecore, every user and role can be a member of several roles. When a security account has
>   been  assigned several roles, the access rights that the different
>   roles possess are added together. The security  account is therefore
>   assigned the accumulated access rights of all the roles that it is a
>   member of. However, if a security account is assigned two roles and
>   one of the roles is denied a specific access right  to an item and the
>   other role is granted this access right to the same item, the access
>   right is denied for  this security account. **In other words, deny
>   always overrules grant when access rights are accumulated.**

Is it possible to do via some sitecore settings or etc ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the behaviour you want then? If someone has both Role 1 and Role 2 - Do you want that person to have see it?

In that case you'll be better off removing inheritance on Role 1 in stead of denying access. Denying access basically tells Sitecore to start over from a specific point. Role 2 can then get the access again.

Have a read through this: [Best Practices from TheClientView](http://theclientview.net/2011/04/sitecore-recommended-practices-part-3-security-roles-and-users/). The very first example sounds like what you're trying to achieve:

> There is a role A that denies a write access to a “/home/contact us”
>   item. 
>       There is a role B that allows write access to the item. There is a user AB that 
>       should have power of both roles A and B. But due to explicit deny permission on 
>       the item, the user won’t be able to get write access on it. When you break the 
>       security inheritance it sets permissions into default deny state, which could be 
>       overridden, by setting up explicit allow access on a role. But explicit deny 
>       access can never be overridden by explicit allow access.

Comment: Yes this is that i need. But I can't understand how to correct setup checkboxes in security editor. Could you please create a screenshot with security editor for this case ?

Comment: I can't create screenshots from my work, sadly.

If you have access to SDN you should have a read through the Security Cookbook (http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf)